# how to make data base to delete info after some time using php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to delete particular info from data base using only php, after some time without using cron system. How can I realize it?

Comment: You can't.. unless you always verify what you need to delete when an user access your app.. why not using crons?

Comment: Because i'm not familiar with cron at all

Comment: is not that hard.. there are a lot of examples out there on how to use crons.. I think you should give it a try because is the best approach for this..

Comment: @pavel Just because you are not familiar with something, does not mean you can *learn* it and use it ;-) Cron-jobs are an amazing tool to have in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Without cron there is only one way i.e hook that deletion code with some event e.g login of any user. As a new user logs in you can run that code

Answer (score 0):

Include a timestamp in the database table. Then have a function in your PHP that deletes all records that are more than X minutes old whenever the PHP is run.

You can use a query such as this (for all records more than a day old).

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `timestamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```